# Unable to install Google APIs Eclipse Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, google-api, eclipse-indigo

I am trying to install the Google APIs Eclipse Plugin, on Eclipse v3.7 (Indigo). I have tried both from a local copy of the archive (ZIP file) and online through Eclipse's "Install New Software" feature, but am unable to get it working. Instead, I constantly get these messages:

> Multiple Problems have occurred:
>   An internal error occurred during "Install download0".
>   Install download0
>   Install download0
>   Install download1
>   Install download2
>   Install download2

Clicking more information brings up this:

> An internal error occurred during: "Install download0".
>   Comparison method violates its general contract!

The error log says:

```
    Error closing the output stream for osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.0.200.20111228-1245 on repository file:/C:/eclipse/.

    Stack trace:

    eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
    java.version=1.7.0_09
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

    This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\Hiromi\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
    Created Time: 2013-05-25 21:15:24.600

    Error
    Sat May 25 21:22:55 BST 2013
    Error closing the output stream for osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.0.200.20111228-1245 on repository file:/C:/eclipse/.

    java.io.IOException: Error unzipping C:\Users\Hiromi\AppData\Local\Temp\org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.0.200.20111228-12454266317341648757159.jar: Invalid zip file format
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.helpers.FileUtils.unzipFile(FileUtils.java:75)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository$ZippedFolderOutputStream.close(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:185)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository$ArtifactOutputStream.close(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:244)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:191)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:122)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:664)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

and also:

```
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ning.async-http-client,1.6.3.201112281337
```

and:

```
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.netty,3.2.4.Final-201112281337
```

I am 100% certain that I am downloading the Eclipse 3.7 version of the plugin, and none of the other fixes listed on the internet have helped. Any help is greatly appreciated, and if any other information is required I am more than happy to provide it - thank you very much!

Comment: You are downloading a plugin for App Engine?

Comment: No- this is a plugin for Eclipse IDE 3.7 for Android Development. I need the Google APIs Plugin in order to integrate Google Drive into my application. Unless that uses App Engine? (I don't think it does)

Comment: Yaa. Some say that `Comparison method violates its general contract!"` kind of error came from a bug, if you are using JRE 7. Insted if you use JRE 6, it might solve the problem. I am not sure though but might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, I might give that a try. How can I install JRE 6 though - I've only got JRE 7 according to Eclipse Preferences??

Comment: I think the way to get JRE 6 is would be to uninstall JRE 7 and the install JRE 6. Or you can also just install JRE 6 and then ask eclipse to use JRE 6. I think I saw some stackoverflow questions on that.

Answer (score 0):

You must download Android Development Bundle [from here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#win-bundle).
With a single download, the ADT Bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps:

Eclipse + ADT plugin

Android SDK Tools

Android Platform-tools

The latest Android platform

The latest Android system image for the emulator

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already got the very latest ADT installed. I'm trying to install the Google API Plugin, which is completely separate. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set java 6 instead of 7 in properties->java compiler.

And update your eclipse, I remember having the same problem. Why to use 3.7 anyways.